# проблема с установкой ssl=on в файле postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с проблемой хочу использовать ssl но почему то при установке параметра ssl = on
в файле postgresql.conf служба postgresql прекращает работу и пишет **Служба "postgresql-x64-13 - PostgreSQL Server 13"
на "Локальный компьютер" была запущена и затем остановлена. Некоторые службы автоматически останавливаются, если они не используются другими службами или программами** с чем это связано?

Вот сообщения журнала:

2021-09-24 22:28:38.240 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: запускается PostgreSQL 13.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
2021-09-24 22:28:38.242 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: для приёма подключений по адресу IPv6 "::" открыт порт 5432
2021-09-24 22:28:38.242 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: для приёма подключений по адресу IPv4 "0.0.0.0" открыт порт 5432
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: запись с hostssl недействительна, так как поддержка SSL отключена
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] ПОДСКАЗКА: Установите ssl = on в postgresql.conf.
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] КОНТЕКСТ: строка 86 файла конфигурации "D:/Programs/Postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf"
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: запись с hostssl недействительна, так как поддержка SSL отключена
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] ПОДСКАЗКА: Установите ssl = on в postgresql.conf.
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] КОНТЕКСТ: строка 88 файла конфигурации "D:/Programs/Postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf"
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: запись с hostssl недействительна, так как поддержка SSL отключена
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] ПОДСКАЗКА: Установите ssl = on в postgresql.conf.
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] КОНТЕКСТ: строка 90 файла конфигурации "D:/Programs/Postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf"
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: запись с hostssl недействительна, так как поддержка SSL отключена
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] ПОДСКАЗКА: Установите ssl = on в postgresql.conf.
2021-09-24 22:28:38.255 MSK [8184] КОНТЕКСТ: строка 91 файла конфигурации "D:/Programs/Postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf"
2021-09-24 22:28:38.286 MSK [14168] СООБЩЕНИЕ: система БД была выключена: 2021-09-24 22:22:18 MSK
2021-09-24 22:28:38.302 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: система БД готова принимать подключения
2021-09-24 22:28:53.953 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: получен запрос на быстрое выключение
2021-09-24 22:28:53.963 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: прерывание всех активных транзакций
2021-09-24 22:28:53.968 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: фоновый процесс "logical replication launcher" (PID 10272) завершился с кодом выхода 1
2021-09-24 22:28:53.973 MSK [10552] СООБЩЕНИЕ: выключение
2021-09-24 22:28:54.014 MSK [8184] СООБЩЕНИЕ: система БД выключена

Answer (score 0):

При включении SSL через параметр `ssl=on` нужно в конфиге указать путь к ключам ([ssl-tcp](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/13/ssl-tcp)).

`ssl_cert_file (string)`
Задаёт имя файла, содержащего сертификат этого SSL-сервера. При указании относительного пути он рассматривается от каталога данных. Этот параметр можно задать только в postgresql.conf или в командной строке при запуске сервера. Значение по умолчанию — server.crt.

`ssl_crl_file (string)`
Задаёт имя файла, содержащего список отзыва сертификатов (CRL, Certificate Revocation List) для SSL-сервера. При указании относительного пути он рассматривается от каталога данных. Этот параметр можно задать только в postgresql.conf или в командной строке при запуске сервера. По умолчанию этот параметр пуст, что означает, что файл CRL не загружается.

`ssl_key_file (string)`
Задаёт имя файла, содержащего закрытый ключ SSL-сервера. При указании относительного пути он рассматривается от каталога данных. Этот параметр можно задать только в postgresql.conf или в командной строке при запуске сервера. Значение по умолчанию — server.key.

Comment: у меня в postgresql.conf на данный момент так настроено: ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = 'd:\\certificates\\root.crt'
ssl_cert_file = 'd:\\certificates\\server.crt'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
ssl_key_file = 'd:\\certificates\\server.key'
ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1.2'
#ssl_max_protocol_version = ''
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = off

Comment: а это pg_hba.conf                                                                                                   
hostssl    all        all       127.0.0.1/32      cert clientcert=verify-full

Comment: при включении параметра ssl=on служба не хочет работать. В просмотре событий, пишет что "Превышено время ожидания запуска сервера". при последующих запусков службы пишет что "2021-09-30 17:51:24.275 MSK [16844] ВАЖНО: файл блокировки "postmaster.pid" уже существует 2021-09-30 17:51:24.275 MSK [16844] ПОДСКАЗКА: Другой экземпляр postmaster (PID 24224) работает с каталогом данных "D:/Programs/Postgresql/data"? " ну это понятно потому что в диспетчере задач PostgreSQL Server фигурирует. Хотя не совсем понятно, почему он работает если служба не запускается.